# Running the firebase emulators when the functions directory is in a different project/location

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am running all the firebase emulators locally on a windows 10 machine.
However I am running my functions emulator separately as the functions dir is in a different project/location.
It appears the triggers are not being emulated and I get the warning below.  Everything apart from the trigger/background functions appears to work fine.

Any solutions?

```
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions
!  hub: emulator hub unable to start on port 4400, starting on 4401 instead.
!  emulators: It seems that you are running multiple instances of the emulator suite for project myproject-dev. This may result in unexpected behavior.
!  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: auth, firestore, database, hosting, pubsub
!  Your requested "node" version "10" doesn't match your global version "12"
!  logging: Logging Emulator unable to start on port 4500, starting on 4501 instead.
!  ui: Emulator UI unable to start on port 4000, starting on 4003 instead.
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
i  functions: Watching "R:\myproject\myprojectCloud\functions" for Cloud Functions...
!  functions: The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.
i  functions[memberUpdate]: function ignored because the firestore emulator does not exist or is not running.
```

Update:
My folder structure.

1. R:/customer/customer-cloud-project/functions
2. R:/cusomer/customer-web-app/

I can run all the emulators in location 2 fine except the functions emulator as there is no functions directory.
So I run the following in location 1 in the functions folder:
firebase emulators:start --only functions

This works fine as it runs 2 instances of the emulator.  However the trigger/background functions do not run as it can't find the firestore emulator running on a different port.

Comment: what do you mean by "the functions dir is in a different project/location"? Do you have multiple projects one with Firestore and the functions in the other? From which directory are you running the each emulator? The more information you provide the easier it would be for us to understand the problem. Right now I'm unable to reproduce your setup.

Comment: I have 2 projects.  One for my cloud functions and one for my front end application which I also have firestore initialized in with rules, indexes etc.  The emulator seems to require a "functions" directory in the same project as the firestore project in order to run them together.  Does that clarify?

Comment: Added more info to the question

Comment: Yes, from my understanding , the "functions" directory has to be located in the same project as the firestore projects .

Comment: @marian.vladoi I found a solution.  Added below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this is to use symbolic links.
This is basically a shortcut to another directory located in the functions project.

If anyone else want to do this the command on Windows is:
mklink /D "R:\firestore-project\functions" "R:\cloud-functions-proj\functions"

You will need to run the command prompt as admin.

See my issue here for more details:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3092#issuecomment-771159457

Note:
You can specify an absolute or relative path when creating the symbolic link.
Relative is the best option otherwise it is unlikely it will work in someone else's environment.  Run this in the dir where you want to create the link:

```
mklink /D "models" "..\..\..\myapp\src\app\models"
```

Comment: For anyone using Mac OS you do
`ln -s ../../path/to/functions functions`
Note: The dots and path are just an example. Change to your relative (or absolute) path.

Comment: Also, remember to update the "source" field in your firestore-project's firebase.json to point to the symlink folder.